# check whether checkbox is checked or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, checked

I want to check whether checkbox is checked or not using jquery. I want to check it on checkbox's onclick event.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:check_action();" id="Public(Web)" checked="checked" value="anyone" name="data[anyone]">
```

Is it possible? How?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `javascript:` in event handler attributes. It's wrong and only works because it happens to be valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: id="Public(Web)" is not a valid id name. ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: @FutureKode: In HTML 4, yes. In HTML 5, no. But for the foreseeable future you're absolutely right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, don't use `javascript:` in event handler attributes. It's wrong and only works because it happens to be valid JavaScript syntax. Second, your `id` is not valid. Parentheses are not allowed in the `id` attribute (in HTML 4 at least; HTML 5 lifts this restriction). Third, if you're using jQuery it probably makes sense to use its `click()` method to handle the `click` event, although be aware that changing it to do that will mean that if the user clicks on the checkbox before the document has loaded then your script won't handle it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Public_Web" checked value="anyone"
    name="data[anyone]">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Public_Web").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("Checked!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, this worked. Thanks for this good one. Thanks to all who answered for this.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use this

```
if($("#checkbox_id").is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this

```
$('#checkbox_id').click(function(){
  alert(this.checked);
});
```

Or using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$('#checkbox_id').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('Checked');
  }
  else{
    alert('Not Checked');
  }
});
```

If you want to do this for all checkbox inside a form, you can use the `:checkbox` filter selector like this:

```
$('#form_id :checkbox').click(function(){
  alert(this.checked);
});
```

Make sure to wrap your code in ready handler:

```
$(function(){
  // code....
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#Public(Web)').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
   alert('Checked');
  } else {
   alert('Not Checked');
  }
 });
</script>

I tried this. but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

There are Several options are there like....

```
1. if($("#ans").is('checked')) 
 2. if($("#ans:checked"))
 3. if($('input:checkbox:checked'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, bind the event in script tags, rather than inline.  This is much easier to follow and makes your HTML far more readable.  <s>Then you can use the jQuery selector `:checked` to determine whether the checkbox is checked.</s>  Then you can use the `checked` attribute of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Public(Web)').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            // do your code here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seriously, no. For checking whether a single checkbox is checked, `$(this).is(':checked')` is simply insane. `this.checked` is better in every conceivable sense.

Comment: Sarcasm, I assume? `$(this).is(':checked')` is a pet peeve of mine, as a symptom of what it represents. Do I need to elaborate?

Comment: Not sarcasm in the slightest -- see my changes!

Comment: Ah, OK. I got into pet peeve tunnel vision attack mode. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
if(!$('#elementid').is(':checked')){
    alert('Not checked');
}else{
    alert('checked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$('##Public_Web').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('Checked');
  }
  else{
    alert('Not Checked');
  }
});
```

If you want to do this for all checkbox inside a form, you can use the `:checkbox` filter selector:

```
$('#form_id :checkbox').click(function(){
  alert(this.checked);
});
```

Make sure to wrap your code in document ready handler:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      // code....
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, notice instead of using a onClick event in the Element itself i would prefer to use a listener, but remove the brackets from the id, It will give you a hard time in some browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<input type="checkbox" id="PublicWeb" checked="checked" value="anyone" name="data[anyone]" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PublicWeb').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert("its checked alright");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" checked/> Change Check Box
```

jquery

```
$("#chkBox").change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
         alert("Checked");
         }
         else {
             alert("Not Checked")
             }
           });
```

```js
 $("#chkBox").change(function() {
 if (this.checked) {
     alert("Checked");
     }
     else {
         alert("Not Checked")
         }
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" checked/> Change Check Box
```